# Enabling SPDY in Firefox 11

Tags: firefox

I wanted to post this Question and answer it because I didn't know where to post this thread on a Mozilla website.

You can now install SPDY on your Apache server with mod_spdy by following [these directions](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/add-spdy-support-to-your-apache-server.html).
I've done this, and in Chrome I can see the green lightning bolt on my site, just like on [Twitter](https://twitter.com) and [Google](https://google.com). Yeah!

Firefox has [an add-on that detects SPDY](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/spdy-indicator/reviews/), but I installed it and still can't see that green lightning bolt. 
Is there any other way to detect SPDY on Firefox? I'm using FF 11 so that shouldn't be the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the answer from a Mozilla developer:
In Firefox 11/12, SPDY support is present but *disabled* by default. You will have to go into about:config and set network.http.spdy.enabled to true.

In Firefox 13+ SPDY is enabled by default. If you are using those and are still not seeing the SPDY icon, please try https://spdytest.com/. If that still does not show the icon, please file a bug at https://github.com/chengsun/moz-spdy-indicator/issues giving details such as OS and Firefox version, and also whether there are any errors related to SPDY indicator in the Error Console.

It is known that Twitter will only sometimes serve HTTPS pages over SPDY.

here's the original thread: https://addons.mozilla.org/addon/spdy-indicator/reviews/345995/